# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin - Crush dumped

Tags: qgis, classification

I installed Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin but it doesn't work. 
After starting QGIS, program displays a message "Please restart QGIS to executing the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. Possible missing dependencies."
Closing the program gets an error "Crush dumped", every time.

I can't uninstall or reinstall this plugin from plugins repositories interface, this also causes "Crush dumped".

I use QGIS 2.14.7 and 2.16.3. Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Comment: Go to your `.qgis2` directory and delete the plugin folder from there (e.g. `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/python/plugins/`. There have been 3 published updates to this plugin _very recently_ so it could very well be that there was a bug and the author(s) addressed this. You could try previous versions of the plugin by downloading from their [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) and extract the plugin folder from the zipped file and place it in the same location mentioned above.

Comment: I did it with versions: 5.0.13, 5.1.1, master - without success.

Comment: The version I last tested successfully was `5.0.10`, maybe try that? I use QGIS 2.16.1 for Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Unfortunetly, I have the same problem with this version.

Comment: I installed QGIS 2.16.3 from downloaded files (not from advanced installer like before) and then Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin was installed correct. And it turns on.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with ubuntu 17.04 and 17.01 running qgis las palmas. It was solved by installing python-matplotlib  and python-scipy

sudo apt-get install qgis python-matplotlib python-scipy

## For QGIS based on Python 3:

sudo apt-get install python3-scipy